# GDIplus Scale Bitmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gdi+

Hello i'm trying to change scale GDIplus::Bitmap and save in memory scaled BItmap, and i have problem. I try many different sample, and my result is NULL. For Example I try change resolution for image, using SetResolution, also i try convert bitmap from image->graphic and use one of constructors  GDIplus::Bitmap scale, but i haven't result. For example i try next code:

```
Bitmap *bitmap = new Bitmap((int32)width, (int32)height,PixelFormat32bppARGB);
bitmap=bmp.Clone(0,0,W,H,PixelFormat32bppPARGB);
mBitmap=(void *)bitmap->Clone(0.0f,0.0f,width,height,PixelFormat32bppPARGB);
```

Answer (score 16):

Compute the new width and height (if you have the scaling factors)

```
float newWidth = horizontalScalingFactor * (float) originalBitmap->GetWidth();
float newHeight = verticalScalingFactor * (float) originalBitmap->GetHeight();
```

or the scaling factors if the new dimensions are known

```
float horizontalScalingFactor = (float) newWidth / (float) originalBitmap->GetWidth();
float verticalScalingFactor = (float) newHeight / (float) originalBitmap->GetHeight();
```

Create a new empty bitmap with sufficient space for the scaled image

```
Image* img = new Bitmap((int) newWidth, (int) newHeight);
```

Create a new Graphics to draw on the created bitmap:

```
Graphics g(img);
```

Apply a scale transform to the Graphics and draw the image

```
g.ScaleTransform(horizontalScalingFactor, verticalScalingFactor);
g.DrawImage(originalBitmap, 0, 0);
```

`img` is now another Bitmap with a scaled version of the original image.

Comment: Thank you! After hours of search, I've found this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution proposed by mhcuervo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083771/9416448)  works well, except if the original image has a specific resolution, for example if it was created by the reading of an image file.

In this case you have to apply the resolution of the original image to the scaling factors:

```
Image* img = new Bitmap((int) newWidth, (int) newHeight);
horizontalScalingFactor *= originalBitmap->GetHorizontalResolution() / img->GetHorizontalResolution();
verticalScalingFactor *= originalBitmap->GetVerticalResolution() / img->GetVerticalResolution();
```

(note: the default resolution for a new `Bitmap` seems to be 96 ppi, at least on my computer)

or more simply you can change the resolution of the new image:

```
Image* img = new Bitmap((int) newWidth, (int) newHeight);
img->SetResolution(originalBitmap->GetHorizontalResolution(),  originalBitmap->GetVerticalResolution());
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e06tc8a5.aspx

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Spiral.png");
Rectangle expansionRectangle = new Rectangle(135, 10,
   myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);

Rectangle compressionRectangle = new Rectangle(300, 10,
   myBitmap.Width / 2, myBitmap.Height / 2);

myGraphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 10, 10);
myGraphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, expansionRectangle);
myGraphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, compressionRectangle);
```

Comment: The question is about to obtain a scaled bitmap out of an existing one. Not drawing the same bitmap at different scales.